# How to non-impredicatively return `Maybe` a lens?

Tags: haskell, lenses, higher-rank-types, impredicativetypes

A type like `Maybe (Lens' a b)` doesn't work because [`Lens'`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.15.1/docs/Control-Lens-Type.html#t:Lens-39-) is under the hood a Rank-2 type, that can't be wrapped in a type constructor without the `-XImpredicativeTypes` extension (which is not really supported in GHC).

What is thus the best type to give a function that would morally have type

```
foo :: A -> Maybe (Lens' B C)
```

A possibility would be to defer the `Maybe` into a passed continuation

```
foo' :: ∀ y . A -> (Lens' B C -> y) -> Maybe y
```

but I don't particularly like that.

Comment: Use [`ALens`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.15.1/docs/Control-Lens-Lens.html#t:ALens) maybe?

Comment: There's also `ReifiedLens` which is just the usual newtype wrapper.around a `Lens`. When you're returning a lens it might be more efficient to use `ReifiedLens` than `ALens`, and it seems about equally convenient for the consumer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is what the [`Control.Lens.Reified`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.15.1/docs/Control-Lens-Reified.html) module is for. It contains `newtype` wrappers for the `lens` hierarchy.

```
foo :: A -> Maybe (ReifiedLens' B C)
```